# ggplot with two Y axes

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

```
dataframe:-  df

  Period        v1      v2
1   2002        1       1
2   2003        5       12
3   2004        9       28
4   2005        16      66
5   2006        23      115

Code:-

ggplot() + geom_line(data=df, aes(x=Period, y=v1, group=1, color="v1")) + 
geom_line(data=df, aes(x=Period, y=v2, group=1, color="v2"))+ theme(legend.title=element_blank()) + scale_y_continuous(name="Count") +
geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Period, y=v1, group=1)) + geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Period, y=v2, group=1))
```

I am plotting two line graph along with points.The issue I am experiencing is that the values increase in different magnitude and so one of the line graphs **"v1"** gets condensed at the lower end of the scale and thus harder to read. can anyone please advice in solving this? Also can this code be shortened?

Comment: Ggplot doesn't support two y axes because to makes the mapping of the aesthetics to the scales ambiguous (and it's considered bad practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea with `ggplot2` is that you convert your data into so-called long format, where each observation occupies one line:

```
library(tidyr)
plot_data <- gather(df, key, value, -Period)
head(plot_data)
##   Period key value
## 1   2002  v1     1
## 2   2003  v1     5
## 3   2004  v1     9
## 4   2005  v1    16
## 5   2006  v1    23
## 6   2002  v2     1
```

Now, you can map the variable `value` to `y` and `key` to colour to get the same plot easier:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(data=plot_data, aes(x=Period, y=value, colour = key)) + 
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) + 
  geom_point(data=plot_data, aes(x=Period, y=value)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Count")
```

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by the data getting harder to read. Maybe, you want a logarithmic y-axis?

```
ggplot() + geom_line(data=plot_data, aes(x=Period, y=value, colour = key)) + 
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  geom_point(data=plot_data, aes(x=Period, y=value)) +
  scale_y_log10(name="Count")
```

[image]