# Scatter plots, groups and error bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, errorbar

I am struggling with the following issue and would really appreciate your help.

I have the following data (this is just a random example for simplification)

```
x<- c('left', 'left', 'left', 'right', 'right', 'right')
y<- c (0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 0.2)
conf<- c(1.5, 1.7, 3, 2, 3, 1)
df <-data.frame(x,y,conf)
```

I want to do the following plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point()+coord_flip()
```

This generates the following image [see photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abnp0.png). But each of my points (y) has a also certain confidence associated with them (variable conf), which I would like to plot as confidence values on another x axis (that would go on the right hand side in this case and the confidence values would be vertical lines). How do I add this second x axis on the right side of the plot, so that it is numerical and that it plots my values as confidence intervals?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Why are you bothering with `coord_flip` when you could just map `aes(x = y, y = x)`? Your naming convention seems to introduce extra confusion.  To be clear, the uncertainty is not in the name `y` (horizontal) dimension, but in the `x` (vertical) dimension?

Comment: Having two y-axes is [deliberately difficult in ggplot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3099219/903061). However, you could easily `facet_wrap(~ x, ncol = 1)`, map `y = 0` and use a standard `geom_errorbar` to indicate uncertainty.

Comment: I tried make a simple example from my more complex data to be able to present it here and used wrong confusing names. By trying to simplify it I actually made it more complicated. @Gregor thanks the facet_wrap can work too.

Answer (score 4):

using `geom_errorbarh()` you can do this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point()+coord_flip()+ 
    geom_errorbarh(aes( xmax = as.numeric(x)+conf/10, 
                       xmin = as.numeric(x)-conf/10, 
                       height=0))
```

[image]

But as said in other posts it may not be great to have several meaning on your x axis, so you could `facet`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=0, y=y))+geom_point()+ 
     geom_errorbarh(aes( xmax = conf, xmin = -conf, height=0))+
     coord_flip()+facet_wrap(~dir, nrow=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking around a bit, several threads indicate that ggplot is designed to not support what you are looking for and it would generally be bad practice (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806649/ggplot-with-two-y-axes#comment59283221_35806649) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right)).

There seems to be a 'hack' [here](https://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2), which might go a bit further than you want to.

On a side-note: May I ask why you decided to label your y-axis with "x" and your x-axis with "y"?

Comment: the x is x and y is y, i just used cord_flip. (with my actual data i flip the plot as it is better for representation, but doing it with this invented data was pointless and confusing).